# Grafana Loki Helm Chart - Where to define the AWS S3 bucket name in the values.yaml file

Tags: amazon-s3, grafana, bucket, grafana-loki

I tried defining the bucket name under:

https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/67c0b3ed2c1574db85673b796080aa87517b07d7/production/helm/loki/values.yaml#L219
but its throwing invalid bucket name

```
  storage:
    bucketNames:
      chunks: chunks
      ruler: ruler
      admin: admin
    type: s3
    s3:
      s3: null
      endpoint: null
      region: null
      secretAccessKey: null
      accessKeyId: null
      s3ForcePathStyle: false
      insecure: false
      http_config: {}
```

I have created an S3 bucket and using the service account to provide access to the bucket.

Can some one help me with how you have used the S3 bucket using the new helm chart

Comment: Did you change those bucket names to point to _actual_ Amazon S3 buckets in your AWS account? See: [Configure storage | Grafana Loki documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/helm/configure-storage/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can pass the bucket details as below**. Either you can use the single bucket for chunk, ruler and admin or you can use different buckets.

```
loki:
  storage:
    bucketNames:
      chunks: aws-bucket-name
      ruler: aws-bucket-name
      admin: aws-bucket-name
    type: s3
    s3:
      region: aws-region
  auth_enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

tldr: define in the `bucketNames.chunks` field

You can search for the usage of the keywords in the helm-chart repo. For example, the `bucketNames` is used to populate the s3 bucket. See [here](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/67c0b3ed2c1574db85673b796080aa87517b07d7/production/helm/loki/templates/_helpers.tpl#L184).